# Linq to sql : Checking an array of strings in a column values of database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I checked against only one string using where condition like this

```
 vms = vms.Where(x => x.CETIGroup != null && x.CETIGroup.ToLower().Trim().Contains(SearchVM.CETIGroup.ToLower().Trim())).ToList();
```

Now I would like to check against a group of strings:

```
SearchVM.CETIGroup = "Orange,Apple,Banana";
 string[] toSearchFor = SearchVM.CETIGroup.Split(',');
List<string> listCETI= new List<string> (toSearchFor);
```

So I want check if CETIGroup has one of the array element.

```
 vms = vms.Where(x => x.CETIGroup != null && x.CETIGroup.ToLower().Trim().Any(y=> listCETI.Contains(y)).ToList();
```

The above code is not working.

Please help me.

Comment: What is not working? Did you get an error?

Comment: The list has 0 values. I am not able check for the matching rows against an array of strings.

Comment: I would like to show all rows which have CETIGroup = Orange or CETIGroup = Apple or CETIGroup = Banana

Comment: You could always use vms.ToList() as starting point...

Answer (score 0):

You are searching in the wrong direction, I guess it should be:

```
vms = vms.Where(x => x.CETIGroup != null && listCETI.Contains(x.CETIGroup.ToLower().Trim())).ToList();
```